# Неправильная расшифровка сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

Пишу шифровальщик алгоритм такой: каждая буква земенятся на определеноое количество в правою,эти цифры заносятся в ключ.  Функция дешифровки работает некоректно вместо нормального вывода сообщения она выдает ZZZZZZZZ(Вывод программы ниже). Если послание состоит из одной буквы(а) и ключ для нее 3 то дешифрует программа правильно.
Код

```
       alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
       ind = 0
       new_msg=[]
       while True:
           number = key[ind]
           letter = msg[ind]
           new_index = (alphabet.index(letter) - number) % len(alphabet)
           letter = alphabet[new_index]
           new_msg.append(letter)
           ind+=1
           if ind >=len(list(msg)):
               break
       print ("Исходное сообщение:")
       print(new_msg)
```

Вывод пограммы:

```
Зашифровать - 1
Расшифровать - 2
Сгенерировать пароль - 3
Выйти - 0
______________________________
Что вам нужно?1
Исходное сообщение:abc
Зашифрованное сообщение:
['z', 'M', 'S']
Коюч:
[26, 39, 45]
______________________________
Зашифровать - 1
Расшифровать - 2
Сгенерировать пароль - 3
Выйти - 0
______________________________
Что вам нужно?2
Зашифрованное сообщение:zMS
Вводите ключ по числам, если ключ введен впишите число 111
Цифрка ключа 0 :26
Цифрка ключа 1 :39
Цифрка ключа 2 :45
Цифрка ключа 3 :111
[26, 39, 45]
Если ваш ключ введен верно впишите y/n:y
Исходное сообщение:
['Z', 'Z', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в том, что в Python операция вычисления остатка для отрицательных чисел выполняется по математическим правилам, то есть −7 % 4=1 при этом знак остатка совпадает со знаком делителя. Кстити, именно такой подход является корректным ([https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Деление_с_остатком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)) в отличии от некоторых других языков программирования.

Поэтому как только  у вас случается ситуация alphabet.index(letter) < number, new_index принимает значение -1, что как раз и дает ваш символ 'Z'.